# How to import a bacpac to Azure without rebuilding the indexes

Tags: sqlpackage

I'm using sqlpackage to import .bacpac to Azure Databases but once the datas have been imported it starts enabling back the indexes and it takes forever. I would like to skip this part.

I though it was bound to the following parameter : `/p: DisableIndexesForDataPhase=(BOOLEAN TRUE)` but it's defaulted as true and it seems it does not work that way.

Is there a parameter or extention I didnt see that could achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you achieving this is by making a copy of your source database and disabling or droping all the indexes before exporting the BACPAC. After you've imported your data to Azure, you could use a tool like Red Gate SQL Compare or some prepared script to apply back the indexes.